# How many numbers such it $\cos{\frac{n\pi}{2}}+i\sin{\frac{n\pi}{2}}$is purely imaginary

Tags: complex-analysis

let $n\in\{1,2,3,\cdots,100\}$, then such $$\cos{\dfrac{n\pi}{2}}+i\sin{\dfrac{n\pi}{2}}$$ is  purely imaginary,then How many numbers $n$ such this condition

$A:25$

$B:50$

$C:75$

$D:100$

my idea: since $n=1$ then
$$\cos{\dfrac{n\pi}{2}}+i\sin{\dfrac{n\pi}{2}}=\cos{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}+i\sin{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}=i$$ is such it.

$n=2$,then we have
$$\cos{\dfrac{n\pi}{2}}+i\sin{\dfrac{n\pi}{2}}=\cos{\pi}+i\sin{\pi}=-1$$ 
is not such it.

$n=3$,then we have
$$\cos{\dfrac{n\pi}{2}}+i\sin{\dfrac{n\pi}{2}}=\cos{\dfrac{3\pi}{2}}+i\sin{\dfrac{3\pi}{2}}=-i$$ 
is such it

and so on

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is correct. To get to a formal proof you can note that "purely imaginary" means that the real part is zero, so you are solving for the $n$ such that $\cos(n\pi/2)$ is zero.

Comment: so $n=2k-1$ is purely imaginary?

Comment: @nanchangjian: Yep :)

Comment: Oh,Thank you so this problem result is choose $B$?

Comment: @nanchangjian: You know that the answer is B, you know why the answer is B, and you know how to prove that the answer is B. My validation should be far less convincing to you than any of those.